# How to do a simple calculator

Tags: javascript, string, integer, arguments, calculator

The task is to implement a function , a simple addition and subtraction calculator that:

- Takes three arguments, two integers, firstArg, SecondArg and a string operation that is either "+" or "-"
- Returns a value depending on operation:
  If operation is + then it returns the sum of the firstArg with the secondArg.
  If operation is - then ir returns the subtraction of the firstArg with the secondArg.
  If operation isn't none then it returns "invalid operation"

Can someone help?

Comment: How would you like us to help? See more in the [help/on-topic] --- _"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."_

Answer (score 0):

```
function name(a0, a1, a2) {
  return a2 === "+"? a0 + a1: a0 - a1;
}
```

Comment: `return (operation=="+")?firstArg+SecondArg:(operation== "-")?firstArg-SecondArg:"invalid operation";`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function, as you asked:

```
const calculator = function(firstArg, secondArg, operationType) {
    if (operationType === '+') {
        return firstArg + secondArg;
    } else if (operationType === '-') {
        return firstArg - secondArg;
    }
}
```

Comment: `else return "invalid operation";`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the function as you asked. The switch statement in JavaScript can be learnt about [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp). If you wanted to use something maybe slightly simpler have a look at the other answers.

```
function simpleAdditionAndSubtractionCalculator(num1, num2, operatorType) {
    switch(operatorType) {
        case "-":
            return num1 - num2;
            break;
        case "+":
            return num1 + num2;
            break;
        default:
            return "Invalid operation!";
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function process (operation, a, b) {
    if(operation === '+'){
        return a + b;
    }else if(operation === '-'){
        return a - b;
    }else{ 
        return "invalid operation";
    }
}

console.log( process('+',3,5) );
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use js **eval** function

```
function simpleAdditionAndSubtractionCalculator(num1, num2, operatorType) {
    return eval(num1 + operatorType + num2)
}
```